# JS/Meteor: Returning 'checked' if string is found in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have created a form where if the checkbox of an option is checked, upon form submission, it passes the value of checked inputs to an array of strings (`cuisineType`, within the `venueAttributes` subschema).

I'm trying to build the equivalent update form and I need to:

1. Find if the value field (ex:'american') of the input is in the array.
2. Return 'checked' (or mark the checkbox as selected) if the value is contained in the array.

This is what I have so far, but not sure if I'm on the right path. Should I use `._find()` in underscore?

```
<label>Type of Cuisine</label>
{{#each venueAttributes.cuisineType}}
  <div class="form-group" id="cuisineForm">     
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" checked="???" name="american" id="american" value="american">American</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" checked="???" name="french" id="french" value="french">French</label>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Thank you for any insights you could provide! 
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're iterating over `venueAttributes.cuisineType` anyway you only need one sub-item:

```
<template name="cuisines">
<label>Type of Cuisine</label>
{{#each venueAttributes.cuisineType}}
  <div class="form-group" id="cuisineForm">     
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" checked={{isChecked}} name={{this}}
        id={{this}} value={{this}}>{{this}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Now you need an `isChecked` helper to decide whether or not a given item is checked.

```
Template.cuisines.helpers({
  isChecked: function(){
    return ( checkedCuisines.indexOf(this) > -1 );
  }
});
```

But, problem!

Your question says:

> passes the value of checked inputs to an array of strings
>   (cuisineType, within the venueAttributes subschema).

But you're looping over `venueAttributes.cuisineType` in this template so by definition the array only contains items that were previously checked. I use a different array `checkedCuisines` to check against but that means that the object you're iterating over in the template has to include all cuisine types, not just the ones that have been checked. Somewhere you need a collection or array of all cuisine types to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks Michel! I've stumbled upon a tutorial doing it in this manner, but I wanted to avoid the creation of another comparison array/collection as I'm going to have a limited number of cuisineTypes (and that means I'd have to maintain it as well). I was intending to still keep all of the possible input elements in the HTML for each option (american, french, etc) and just change the checked/not checked attribute of the HTML for each one using a helper that checks if the value (or a hardcoded string that I pass as a parameter of the helper) is present in the array (using find()?)